# How to paint rounded and square points in OpenGL

Tags: c++, opengl

I am use below code for draw rounded points,

```
glEnable(GL_POINT_SMOOTH);
glEnable(GL_BLEND);
glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
```

but, i need to paint two different points, one square and one rounded.

Example, when use only:

```
glEnable(GL_POINTS)
```

i know the square point is painted: ■

and with

```
glEnable(GL_POINT_SMOOTH);
glEnable(GL_BLEND);
glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
```

i know the rounded point is painted: ●

I have 2 methods for painting diferents objects.
My method for square point:

```
MyClass::squarePoint()
{
    glPointSize(10.0);
    glEnable(GL_PROGRAM_POINT_SIZE);
    glBegin(GL_POINTS);
    glEnd();
}
```

and my method for rounded point:

```
MyClass::roundedPoint()
{
    glPointSize(10.0);
    glEnable(GL_PROGRAM_POINT_SIZE);
    glEnable(GL_POINT_SMOOTH);
    glEnable(GL_BLEND);
    glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
    glBegin(GL_POINTS);
    glEnd();
}
```

and my paintGL method just in case:

```
MyClass::paintGL()
{
    this->squarePoint();
    this->roundedPoint();
}
```

My questions is, how do i prevent square point transform in rounded point when i paint a rounded point?

My problem:

[image: Gif Example]

Comment: Try: `glDisable(GL_POINT_SMOOTH);` `glDisable(GL_BLEND);`. Note, `glEnable(GL_POINTS)` doesn't make any sense and will cause a `GL_INVALID_ENUM ` error - See [`glEnable`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glEnable.xml).  Further note, that drawing by `glBegin`/`glEnd` sequences is deprecated since decades.
See [Vertex Specification](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Vertex_Specification) and [Shader](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Shader) for a state of the art way of rendering.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It's working, but when i dot not use glEnable(GL_POINTS), i can't not paint.

Comment: that is weird ...

Comment: yes, i don't know for what.